# While loop running infinite

Tags: c#, while-loop, conditional-statements

I'm writing the program to receive Int input from user in range of 8 to 12. However, loop goes on to run infinitely if input is less than 8 or greater than 12. Can anyone please guide what I'm doing wrong here?

```
int numLength;
    
Console.WriteLine ("Enter a number:");
    
while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numLength)) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid input.");        
}

while(true) 
{
    if((numLength >= 8) && (numLength <= 12))
        break;
    else
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Only between 8 and 12.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a 'break' statement after 'Console.writeline' in the 'else' section. Without it, your code is not able to exit the inner while loop if values smaller than 8 and larger than 12 are entered. Secondly, the user has no way of re-entering data if values outside the given range are entered. Here is what you need to do instead.

```
while(true)
{
    Console.WriteLine ("Enter a number:");
    
    while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numLength))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid input.");        
    }
        
    if((numLength >= 8) && (numLength <= 12))
        break;
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Only between 8 and 12.");
    }
}
```

Comment: But that would ruin the purpose of the while loop, it should loop infinitly on wrong input and the else block should occure on wrong input.

Comment: Also notice there is no `inner` loop.

Comment: The infinite loop functionality can be catered by the outside loop, although, another input statement is required to make that work, as currently, the only input statement that exists is outside both the loops. This prevents the user from entering new data if values outside the given range are entered.  You can avoid using the break statement by removing the inner loop, OR by adding a second input statement at the end of the inner loop, so that if wrong data is entered, the user is able to re-enter new values

Comment: once again notice OP doesn't have a outer and inner loop - OP has two loops, and it seems you are under the impression I am the OP which is wrong, just giving you feedback on the answer which may solve the infinite loop but with the cost of a lose of OPs desired functionality - could write an anser myself but want to give you the chance :) - the current answer IMHO is insufficient

Comment: You're correct, I misread the brackets, there is no inner loop, thanks for pointing it out. But the reason for the infinite looping remains the same. I have edited my answer with the correct solution. 
P.S. The 'you' was meant generally :)

Answer (score 2):

It's because in the case where the input is a valid integer but not between 8 and 12, you do not allow the user to re-enter a number. You would need to do `ReadLine()` again after you do the print `Console.WriteLine("Only between 8 and 12.");` but then you'd need to make sure the input is valid again.

I suggest changing the code structure a bit, using a do while and saving the result of `ReadLine()` to a variable and doing both checks after.

e.g.

```
int numLength;
bool isValid = false;
bool isRightLength = false;

do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a number:");
    isValid = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numLength);

    if (isValid)
    {
        isRightLength = (numLength >= 8) && (numLength <= 12);

        if (!isRightLength)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Only between 8 and 12.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        isRightLength = false;
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid input.");
    }
}
while (!isValid || !isRightLength);
```